# Android database - which thread to use

Tags: android, sqlite

Is it necesary to ALWAYS query the android sqlite database in background thread? In case of small amount of data, can I use the main thread?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the main thread, just make sure that your data size won't increase in the future, or you'll have to move to an `AsyncTask` or similar implemenation.

Edit:

Just to clarify, it's bad practice to do any database access on the main thread, but it is not forbidden.

Comment: Thanks. What amount of data needs to be then queried in AsynchTask ?

Comment: It depends on your application needs, I'd recommend always doing it in a background task, but _technically_ the main thread is allowed.